# How can I use the AWS SDK within an app that is hosted on AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

I've built a Next.js app that uses the v3 AWS SDK to do things like send emails and upload files to S3.

Locally, this works fine—I have my `~/.aws/credentials` file set up.

I'm running the app on AWS Amplify. This also works fine apart from the operations that need the SDK.

To pick up credentials, the [SDK docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html) that the environment variables need to have these names:

```bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

When I go to add these as environment variables (like if I was hosting on Vercel or Netlify), I can see that Amplify reserves the `AWS_` prefix, but according to [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html), does not provide an access key ID or secret access key.

Those docs recommend using the parameter store to store environment secrets, which I guess these qualify as.

I've done that, but having them stored "in `process.env.secrets` as a JSON string" is of limited use since the SDK won't automatically pick them up that way.

I've tweaked my `amplify.yml` file based on another StackOverflow answer I saw to copy the secrets from build time to run time, but while this lets me `console.log` the values I set in the parameter store, it doesn't necessarily get me any closer to the SDK "just working" the way it's apparently supposed to:

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e secrets >> .env.production # make selected env vars available at runtime  
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - .next/cache/**/*
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I guess I could do stuff like this in my code:

```js
const { AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY } = JSON.parse(process.env.secrets)

const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  }
});
```

I'm a little nervous about accidentally exposing the credentials in a place they shouldn't be, especially since I'm now just blindly copying examples from about five different AWS docs and don't have much of a feel for the security implications.

I think the above solution will break it locally too.

**What's the intended way of doing this, and why is it so apparently under-documented?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting credentials for logged in user via Amplify Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74410689/getting-credentials-for-logged-in-user-via-amplify-auth)

Comment: i don't think so—this doesn't have anything to do with authenticating users to the application, which is what that question seems to be about

Comment: Well you shouldn’t have those credentials on the front end

Comment: You appear to be using Amplify Hosting for this webapp but the webapp itself does not use the [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/) library, which abstracts S3 storage and other AWS services for you. Instead, your webapp uses the native AWS JavaScript SDK so your front-end needs some way to get STS credentials so that it can call AWS APIs. Do you have a back-end that can authenticate your users and supply them with STS credentrials?